# Azure Cost Management - how to match ResourceGuid with ResourceId

Tags: azure, cost-management

I have a sponsored Azure subscription thanks to our partnership with Microsoft.
I have the ability to export usage from a dedicated web Site (Azure SponsorShip).

Unfortunately in the CSV file I received, I have only ResourceGUID and not ResourceId... And I don't know how to match these Ids.
Any ideas to find the Id related to a Resource Guid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resource GUID is different which denotes the Deployment GUID of the service. To get the breakdown of which resources are actually contributing towards the costs.

If you refer to the page [`Understand your bill for Microsoft Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/understand/review-individual-bill), you can see the description for the "Resource GUID" property:

> The billed meter identifier. This is used as the identifier used to
>   price billing usage.

If you'd like to manually know the resource name which you are being billed for you can log into the Azure Account Center, click "Billing History" and download the usage details for the current period. This information is being updated daily, and you even get usage information with a daily breakdown

Comment: Is it something also true when it is a sponsored account? Because in our case, what you called the Azure Account Center is replaced by the Microsoft Azure Sponsorship web site (https://www.microsoftazuresponsorships.com/) and the only thing we can download is the CSV file with only ResourceGUIDs...

Comment: This is a really odd design choice from Microsoft... so there is NO way to match the cost back to a Resource Group or Resource...